# wicket - two submit buttons with different validation

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I am using two AjaxButton for the same grid where both of them are not in the form but attached to it.

```
activateButton = new AjaxButton(ACTIVATE_BUTTON, grid.getForm())

blockButton = new AjaxButton(BLOCK_BUTTON, grid.getForm())
```

my problem is trying to give each one of them different validation, when the form is submitted i am getting all the buttons validation instead of getting just one of them as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of the buttons you can disable the default form processing using [AjaxButton.setDefaultFormProcessing()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Button.html#setDefaultFormProcessing%28boolean%29) and handle the validation directly in the button by overriding [AjaxButton.onSubmit()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Button.html#onSubmit%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off default form processing and control validation manually. 
See [wicket manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/multiple-submit-buttons.html)